# BSOD caused by minimizing games and long inactivity periods

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Sort not the first pc which reacts the same way. Variety of games but one of the few great examples Dota 2 and Assassins Creed series. When I do alt-tab and say work , listen to music then don't turn off pc for around 48 hours with one of the example games minimized(alt-tabbed). At some point I am pretty certain you will get BSOD. I don't usually encounter bsod since I run verifier with all drivers on periodically - delete offending applications such as Daemon Tools(never use that).

And games never produce bsod during the playing.

Is there anyway to keep games minimized for long periods? Sort of bad habit. Just lost piece of dissertation work - great.

I suspect it has to do with extensive multi threading as I usually have around 20 applications running and a game minimized.

DMP File: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndkb1qw44g34l9t/112513-5850-01.dmp

Dump details:

```
Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0x1e3
nt!WheaReportHwError+0x263
hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x4c
hal!HalpMceHandler+0x9e
hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous+0x55
hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x40
nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x6c
nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x153
hal!HalpCmciService+0x59


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel

IMAGE_NAME:  GenuineIntel

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_MEMORY__UNKNOWN

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_MEMORY__UNKNOWN

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Comment: This problem is unique to your system.  So lets start with the basics.  Are you running all current device and intel chipset drivers?

Comment: Yes of course. If anyone could test it I am sure it is repeatable on other system. My laptop behaves the same yet configurations are quite different. Last PC BSOD was 3 months ago. Since then I think it was restarted automatically 3 times by unforgiving windows update.

Comment: Its not repeatable.  Unless you post the information I requested I cannot help you. **This is a driver problem**

Comment: upload the dmp file, not this useless text

Comment: @magicandre1981 slow down a little. 1. How do I upload dmp file to the resource which only accepts images? 2. How do I check if I run all current device and intel chipset drivers?

Comment: upload the file to your skydrive/dropbox account and insert a link to your post

Comment: Ok for 2. pls name the software or win7 feature - I will do the rest.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Link is added , thx.

Comment: I posted the answer. I use Windbg.exe to analyze the dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the L2 Cache (`GCACHEL2_EVICT_ERR` - a generic transaction type experienced a level-2 cache error during a cache eviction event):

```
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa800fbc8028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01cee0e849442404
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 873
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 11/25/2013 23:52:47 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Memory
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800fbc80a8
Section       @ fffffa800fbc8180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 73
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Physical Addr.: 0x0000000106a87540

===============================================================================
Section 1     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800fbc80f0
Section       @ fffffa800fbc81c9
Offset        : 417
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306a9
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000001

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa800fbc8138
Section       @ fffffa800fbc8289
Offset        : 609
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : GCACHEL2_EVICT_ERR (Proc 1 Bank 8)
```

Update the BIOS of your [ASUS P8Z77-V LX](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z77V_LX/#support) from Version 1603

```
BiosVersion = 1603
BiosReleaseDate = 01/07/2013
BaseBoardManufacturer = ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BaseBoardProduct = P8Z77-V LX
```

to 2204 which has memory fixes. Maybe it also fixes your issue. Also make sure your Intel  i7-3770K doesn't overheat.

Comment: Wow so much precise information for my system without even me telling. Applauding. Accepting.